# Dialog box alert edittext empty and need to fill it

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying put the all alert box in my code.. but still can't run... when the `editText` in empty or null. It will show a dialog box which is needed to be filled by user. I've already tried all the steps and all dialog alert box. But it still functional. but in my case... this is more than 3 edittext involve. Just need an opinion where should I put the code for error empty edittext and need user fill it before they push the button.

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputPrice;
EditText inputDesc;

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://192.168.0.102/android_connect/create_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

//private static final CharSequence TITLE_DIALOG = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
    inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);



    // Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

    // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {


            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
     /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<EditText> editTextList = new ArrayList<EditText>();
        //editTextList.add(myEditText);
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();
        for(EditText inputName : editTextList)
        {

        if (name == null || inputName.getText().toString().length() == 0)
        {   

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence error = "Please enter a track name" + name;
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, error, duration);
            toast.show();


        }
        else {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        }
        return null;

    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: for alert create a common method and call it every where in your whole class where you want to show alert

Answer (score 0):

I actually would do this quite a bit differently... The error checking code should be a part of the Dialog onClick button. Check to see if all of the values are entered, and if they are not, put an indicator that the user needs to fill in that box, all while not finishing the dialog.  Here's an example of this from one of my programs, in this case, getting a name to add to a high scores routine.

```
EditText input;
input=new EditText(this.getApplicationContext());
final int index=i;
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
     .setTitle("Update Status")
     .setMessage(R.string.getName)
     .setView(input)
     .setPositiveButton(sayings_array[rnum], new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
             Editable value = input.getText();
             String name=value.toString();
             if (name!=null)
             {
                 addToHighScore(name,level,score,index);
                 dialog.dismiss();
             }
        }
 }).show();
```

Comment: where actually i need to put it?? in onclickListener or else??

Comment: Note that I get the values in the `onClick` routine, verify they are good, and then pass them to another function meant for handling the output of the dialog, before dismissing them. The key is the innermost `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Check Edittext for null before starting `AsyncTask` execution. just first check EditText for empty on button click first then start `CreateNewProduct` `AsyncTask` . change your code as:

```
 // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

       String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

        if (name != null || inputName.getText().toString().length() != 0)
        {   

           if (price != null || price.getText().toString().length() != 0)
            {  
              if (description != null || description.getText().toString().length() != 0)
                { 
                  // creating new product in background thread
                  new CreateNewProduct().execute();
                }
               else{
                      //show alert here
                }

           }else{
         //show alert here
           }


        }else{
         //show alert here
        }

        }
    });
```

Comment: i already use your code but it still appears my dialog box while i running... can you give a link or other code for me to dialog box alert.. my code cant use it..

Comment: @user1906140 : can you post  your latest code in question with my suggestion

Comment: @user1906140 : see my answer why you are using if (name == null) use name !=null